# Why I can't retrieve and print the tag name of an element retrieved from my DOM in this JQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am pretty new in JavaScript and JQuery and I am going crazy trying to retrieve the tag name of an object that represent a tag.

This is my **JQuery** script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("thead.opening").click(function () {

     alert("INTO FIRST FUNCTION !!!");

     var theadElement = $(this);
     var tbodyElement = $(this).next();

     alert("THEAD TAG BEFORE: " + theadElement.tagName());

     $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
         $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
         $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
         $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");

         alert("THEAD TAG AFTER: " + theadElement.tagName());
     });

     return false;
});
```

As you can see this is automatically performed when the user click on a **thead** object having CSS class **opening** setted, so the **$(this)** should represent the clicked **thead** element into the DOM (is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?).

So I put this element referecence into the **theadElement** variable, by this line:

```
var theadElement = $(this);
```

So this **theadElement** should contain the reference of the clicked thead in the DOM.

Now I want to retrieve and print the tag associated to this element (the **thead** tag) so I try to do:

```
alert("THEAD TAG BEFORE: " + theadElement.tagName());
```

But, doing in this way, trying to perform this script it crash and into the FireBug console I obtain this error message:

```
TypeError: theadElement.tagName is not a function
http://localhost:7001/wea-web/edi.do?serv=8.2
Line 32
```

Why it don't work? What am I missing? How can I retrieve the tag name of the element associted to the **theadElement** object?

Tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) is a property of the dom element not a function so

```
alert("THEAD TAG BEFORE: " + this.tagName);
```

or since `theadElement` is a jQuery object

```
alert("THEAD TAG BEFORE: " + theadElement.prop('tagName'));
```

or

```
alert("THEAD TAG AFTER: " + theadElement[0].tagName);
```

Comment: mmm using the JQuery version (the one that use the .prop() function) I obtain this error message: TypeError: theadElement.prop is not a function
http://myServer:7001/wea-web/edi.do?serv=8.2
Line 32. Why? It could depend by the fact that in this project is used an old version of JQuery (the 1.9.1.min.js)? 
Using this.tag name I obtain "THEAD TAG BEFORE: undefined" as output

Comment: try `theadElement.attr('tagName')` or `theadElement[0].tagName`

Comment: Ok these both seems to works fine !! But what these statment works and the prop() function don't works? Is it something related to my JQuery version or what? And why this.tagName give me an undefined object but theadElement[0].tagName works fine? What represent the theadElement array?

Comment: @AndreaNobili what is the jQuery version used,, the `.prop` was added in jQuery 1.6

Comment: Into the project I have these files related to JQuery: jquery.js (opening it and reading the inner comments there is written "jQuery 1.2.3 - New Wave Javascript" and jquery-1.9.1-min.js and jquery-ui.js